# Realtime update fps Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousemove

I have these functions that control the fps of a moving object.

I would like to change the fps based on the `mousemove`. Any idea how to do this?

Here is the part of the function I'm using:

```
(function () {


    var $example = $('#circview .example');
    var exampleLeft = $example.offset().left;
    var exampleWidth = $example.width();
    var frame = $example.find('.frame')[0];
    var motio = new Motio(frame, {
        frames: 36

    });


        $example.mousemove(function(event){ 
        var ycoord =  event.pageX ;

     
        
        motio.play();
        motio.set('fps', ycoord);
    });
```

Comment: Umm, use the `mousemove` event?

Comment: Im using the mousemove event, but im doing it wrong. Any idea how to use it in the context of this function?

Comment: Can you elaborate "change the fps based on the mousemove"?

Comment: When I move the mouse, Im looking for the ycoord to update in the motio.set('fps', ycoord) bit

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice you were using the event already. So what's the problem? Doesn't the event trigger?

Comment: yes, thats right the event doesnt trigger. The fps seems fixed. when I move the mouse it doesnt change

Comment: What is `Motio`? What framework are you using? Please link it.

Comment: Hi, its this one http://darsa.in/motio/ it basically controls a sprite image, If you go to the examples section and click on the 360 view you can see a demo